# C# Linq error 'DbSet() .GroupJoin( inner: DbSet(), outerKeySelector: ' could not be translated

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to rewrite an old select query to EF Core in lamdba expression but it is throwing the following error.

```
        var users=  
            (
                (from e in this.dbContext.Users
                join t in this.dbContext.Titles
                on e.UserId equals t.UserId
                into et
                join d in this.dbContext.Dept
                on e.DeptId equals d.DeptId
                from et_left in et.DefaultIfEmpty()  
                select 
                {
                    UserId = UserId 

                    EntryDate=e.EntryDate,
            Extension = et_left.Extension,
                }));
```

This compiles and execute without any error. When I step and check the users, I can't see the count in my test.
It return an Queryable object the code continues to filter like the folloing

users= users(s => s.IsActive("Y"));

it does work but hovering over users object does not shows the result

The LINQ expression 'DbSet() .GroupJoin( inner: DbSet(), outerKeySelector: e => e.UserId, innerKeySelector: t => t.UserId, resultSelector: (e, et) => new { e = e, et = et })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

```
        var users=  
            (
                (from e in this.dbContext.Users
                join t in this.dbContext.Titles
                on e.UserId equals t.UserId
                into et
                join d in this.dbContext.Dept
                on e.DeptId equals d.DeptId
                from et_left in et.DefaultIfEmpty()  
                select new UserViewModel
                {
                    UserId = UserId 

                    EntryDate=e.EntryDate,
            Extension = et_left.Extension,
                })).ToList();
```

I am not sure when I add the .ToList is throwing an error

I would like to covert to List to update the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place second `from` when doing left join exactly after `join`. Also you can reuse alias from join.

```cs
var users =  
    from e in this.dbContext.Users
    join t in this.dbContext.Titles on e.UserId equals t.UserId into et
    from t in et.DefaultIfEmpty()  
    join d in this.dbContext.Dept on e.DeptId equals d.DeptId
    select new UserViewModel
    {
        UserId = UserId 

        EntryDate = e.EntryDate,
        Extension = t.Extension,
    };
```